# Obtener valor de campo bit en un Gridview con c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview

Tengo un `GridView` de sólo lectura, donde uno de sus campos se muestra con un `CheckBox`, ya que el campo a mostrar es del tipo `bit`, se muestra perfecto dependiendo de su valor (0/1), intento recuperar su valor desde el evento `RowDataBound` de la `GridView` para mostrar unos valores, pero no hay caso, el valor de  `e.Row.Cells[7].Text` es vacío, o sea "" y yo sé perfectamente que hay registros con el valor 1.

¿Que puede estar pasando?

Gracias

Comment: Se muestra en un campo de tipo checkbox? y lo tratas de obtener con la propiedad text? no sera algun otra propiedad?

Comment: defines los campos en tiempo de diseño? esa columna con checks es un BoundField o un TemplateField ?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, el campo de la tabla es del tipo bit, en la grilla se muestra como un checkbox, pero en el RowDataBound de la grilla, la única forma (al menos es la que conozco) puedo recuperar el valor mediante_ e.Row.Cells [7].Text_, y esta me devuelve vacío

Comment: Hola Leandro, los campos para la gridview no los defino de antemano, lleno el Gridview con una función donde bindeo el resultado de una consulta a la grilla.

Comment: El valor es vacio, lo que no es vacio es el valor de tu checkbox, para eso debes buscar o instanciar un elemento chekcbox CheckBox check = ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[7].FindControl("nombre_o_id_de_tu_checkbox"));